# Loopback: PersistentModel - updateAll (reference to item)

Tags: loopback

What I would like is to change the value of ALL the items to one value (another property)

like

MyModel.updateAll({}, {property1: property2});

In my specific case I have model with two properties (versionHash and previousVersionHash)...

I have a list of items that are upserted, but before I want to update all the items' previousVersionHash to versionHash, and then update all upserted one with the new versionHash.

any idea how to do this as fast as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid LoopBack query language does not support this use case. My recommendation is to execute a custom (SQL) query.

If you are using an SQL database, then please refer to the following documentation page: [Executing native SQL](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Executing-native-SQL.html). Example implementation:

```
await dataSource.connector.execute(
  'UPDATE MyTable SET previousVersionHash=versionHash'
);
```

If you are using a different database, then please check the connector documentation and/or the source code to find out what is the syntax of `dataSource.connector.execute` API.